# Django: Limiting or excluding choices in a tuple for modelchoices

Tags: python, django

I am seeking assistance regarding this matter, I am trying to limit or exclude choices in the `APPLICANT_DATA` or is it even possible? The data is displayed only in the admin.

```
APPLICANT_STAT = (
    (0, 'For Initial Interview'),
    (1, 'For Intial Exam'),
    (2, 'For Final Interview'),
    (3, 'For Training'),
    (4, 'For Evaluation Exam'),
    (5, 'For Evaluation'),
    (6, 'HIRED'),
    (7, 'FAILED'),
    (8, 'Fired/Retired'),
)
class APPLICANT_DATA(models.Model):
    APP_STATUS =  models.IntegerField(choices=APPLICANT_STAT, default=0)
```

Something like this to limit the choices:

```
APP_STATUS =  models.IntegerField(choices=APPLICANT_STAT[0][5], default=0)
#does not work obviously
```

Or is there another way like limiting it in the admin field? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the choices, you could just do

```
APP_STATUS = models.IntegerField(choices=APPLICANT_STAT[:5], default=0)
```

If you want to select specific values, you need to create a new tuple or list. For example, to use the first and the third values of `APPLICANT_STAT`:

```
APP_STATUS = models.IntegerField(choices=(APPLICANT_STAT[0], APPLICANT_STAT[2]), default=0)
```

Comment: I've been testing codes and forgot about that, thanks